# Passing data to a child's STDIN in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to both C# and Perl, but I've been programming in other languages for a few years now. But anyways, I've been trying to write a simple program that passes a value from a C# program to a Perl script via its STDIN. The C# program opens the Perl script just fine, but I cant seem to figure out a way to pass a '1' to it. what would the best way of doing this be? I've searched far and wide for solutions, with no luck...

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OpenPerl
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path ="Z:\\folder\\test.pl";
            Process p = new Process();
            Process.Start(path, @"1");
        }
    }
}
```

The Perl program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Enter 1: ";
my $number=<STDIN>;
if($number==1)
{
    print "You entered 1\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my ($number)=@ARGV;
```

instead of:

```
my $number=<STDIN>;
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): *"The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the script."*

Comment: thanks alot! that did seem to work! the only issue is, i'm going to be working with scripts that have already been written, and i do not know if i'm going to be allowed to modify them. but maybe i'll just make a copy of all the scripts and have my own little versions of them. but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a command line argument to the perl script , not a user input via Process.Start(string,string).

Try printing the @ARGV received by the perl script and you should be able to see 1.

Comment: It's `@ARGV`, not `@argv`. Either way, the op clarified that wants to the pass the value via standard input rather than an argument.

Comment: @ikegami edited my answer, thanks. Sending keystrokes didnt seem like a good idea, so just pointed out the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the perl script to receive its input via STDIN, the C# side would look like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("1");
```

Setting `UseShellExecute` is required for `RedirectStandardInput`, but it may prevent the perl script from starting properly.  In that case, set `FileName="<path to perl.exe>"` and `Arguments="<path to script.pl>"`.